# AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo una **tabla** con `DefaultTableModel` donde muestro los datos de clientes.

Tengo 7 columnas. **¿Por qué me sale ese error de excepción al darle el ancho de las columnas?**

Código:

```
public class Listado_clientes extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Printable{
    public Listado_clientes() {
        initComponents();

        //Situamos el JDialog en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //No redimensionable.
        setResizable(false);

        try {
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            tabla_clientes.setModel(modelo);

            //Dar ancho a las columnas de la tabla. --> aquí el problema.
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(110);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(90);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(140);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(70);
            tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(130);

            //Realizamos la consulta.
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection con = Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda");

            String sql = "SELECT dni, nombre, apellidos, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email FROM clientes";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

            modelo.addColumn("DNI");
            modelo.addColumn("NOMBRE");
            modelo.addColumn("APELLIDOS");
            modelo.addColumn("TELEFONO");
            modelo.addColumn("DIRECCION");
            modelo.addColumn("CIUDAD");
            modelo.addColumn("EMAIL");

            //Crear las columnas de la tabla.
            /*for (int i=0; i<tabla_clientes.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            }*/

            //Recorrer el array e imprimir los datos en las celdas.
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
                for (int i=0; i<cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                    filas[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
                }
                modelo.addRow(filas);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Por qué me sale ese error de excepción al darle el ancho de las
>   columnas?

Por que al momento de querer tomar la columna para ajustar el ancho resulta que el modelo de la tabla está vacío, no hay columnas y el método `getColumnCount()` del `DefaultTableModel` devuelve implícitamente un `0`.

La solución mas próxima es primero agregar cada columna y después si modificar los tamaños.

```
modelo.addColumn("DNI");
modelo.addColumn("NOMBRE");
modelo.addColumn("APELLIDOS");
modelo.addColumn("TELEFONO");
modelo.addColumn("DIRECCION");
modelo.addColumn("CIUDAD");
modelo.addColumn("EMAIL");

tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(110);
tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(90);
tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(140);
tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(70);
tabla_clientes.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(130);
```